# Drupal installation issue. Strange error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, drupal

So I installed Drupal 8 beta earlier today, and once installed I got the following on localhost/drupal:

[image: screenshot of web browser]

I decided to delete Drupal 8 and get the stable version, just incase this was the issue. Turns out I have it for the stable version also.

Could possibly be a apache2.conf issue? But I'm new to Drupal, and have no other problems with other sites not using the CMS.

Thank you for your time.

edit:

```
handle($request) // Handle the response object.    ->prepare($request)->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response); } catch (HttpExceptionInterface $e) { $response = new Response($e->getMessage(), $e->getStatusCode()); $response->prepare($request)->send(); } catch (Exception $e) { $message = 'If you have just changed code (for example deployed a new module or moved an existing one) read http://drupal.org/documentation/rebuild'; if (Settings::get('rebuild_access', FALSE)) { $rebuild_path = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . '/rebuild.php'; $message .= " or run the rebuild script"; } // Set the response code manually. Otherwise, this response will default to a // 200. http_response_code(500); print $message; throw $e; }
```

Comment: I can't actually read that screen shot. Why not just copy and paste the message?

Comment: Seems to be like PHP isn't even interpreted. Can you confirm that PHP works on your setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking in your http.conf file located at: `/private/etc/apache2`

ensure that `#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` is uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

if you install the new version of php (php7 in my case) you should install

```
  sudo apt-get install libphp7.0-embed
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted in a similar thread https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2016-12-21/localhost-is-down#comment-14591819

But sharing here as well:

for my situation, I got this error when upgrading from PHP 7 to PHP 8

it ended up being that LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so was not being hit.

in the php.conf the code looked like below:

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule !mod_php7.c>
      <IfModule prefork.c>
        LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so
      </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

as you can see if php8, that line was never hit.

once this file was updated to the following, the error was resolved

```
# Cannot load multiple php5, php7, php8 and php modules
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule !mod_php7.c>
    <IfModule !mod_php8.c>
      <IfModule prefork.c>
        LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```